# Make page to tell browser not to cache/preserve input values

Tags: html, browser, forms, browser-cache

Most browsers cache form input values. So when the user refreshes a page, the inputs have the same values.

Here's my problem. When a user clicks *Save*, the server validates POSTed data (e.g. checked products), and if not valid, sends it back to the browser. However, as stated above, even if the server clears selection for some values, they may still be selected because of the browser cache!

My data has invisible (until parent item selected) checkboxes, so the user may be even not aware that some previous value is still selected, until clicking *Save* again and gets an error message - even though the user thinks it's not. Which is irritating.

This can be resolved by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, but it's not even a solution. Is there an automatic/programmatic way to tell browser not to cache form input data on some form/page?

Comment: Is `<form autocomplete="off"...` an option for you? Is this problem occurring across all browsers, or just one in particular?

Comment: Is there a way to answer this question with reference to drop down `<select>` lists. I have a list and have defined a `selected` choice but refreshing the page retains previous selected options.

Comment: I want to achieve the opposite - preserve each page's input values on back button(click back twice-get inputs accordingly). There are various examples around using lot of JS code, (which dont really work IMHO) but - is there a simpler way? I tried autocomplete="on" on both form and input fields-doesn't work. Browser is Chrome.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Are you explicitly setting the values as blank? For example:

```
<input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
```

That should stop browsers putting data in where it shouldn't. Alternatively, you can add the `autocomplete` attribute to the form tag:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...></form>
```

Comment: I talk about checkboxes so I can't set value to "". And, does autocomplete off means not to store form input values "when user presses F5", not only "for dropdown autocompletion list"?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion, autcompletion=off affects "Session history caching", at least in Gecko. I will test if it works for what I need.

Comment: @queen3: Yes, checkboxes are a problem since there is no way to explicitly say "not checked". If you're still having problems, you could try `checked="false"`, it may work in some browsers. Another alternative is to use Javascript/jQuery to explicitly untick all checkboxes on page load.

Comment: @queen3, you mean "autocomplete=off" not "autocompletion=off"

Comment: All of the answers and suggestions didnt work for me. Using chrome and develeoping .net

Comment: @piedpiper Try ModelState.Clear() in your controller action. If you are using return View(...or return PartialView(... then it will return the old values. This is by design for MVC.

Comment: ...adding autocomplete="off" as an input field argument did the trick for me

Answer (score 54):

From [a Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag)

It did not work with value="" if the browser already saves the value so you should add.

For an input tag there's the attribute autocomplete you can set:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

You can use autocomplete for a form too.

Comment: In Chrome, it appears `autocomplete="off"` has no effect when used on individual form-elements - even with `value` attribute explicitly set blank, and while sending a `Cache-Control: Must-Revalidate` header, this had no effect. I had to apply the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the `<form>` element itself to suppress this behavior in Chrome.

Comment: i did autocomplete="off" on form but it didnt work for me

Comment: i need more info @KingsleySimon like browser , and you may have some settings on your browser that prevent the correct behavior

Comment: it seems that browser's behavior has changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: and be noted the html valid form . and for example its not aform inside another etc

Answer (score 13):

Basically, there are two ways to clear the cache:

```
<form autocomplete="off"></form>
```

or

```
$('#Textfiledid').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 10):

Another approach would be to reset the form using JavaScript right after the form in the HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" value="" name="myTextInput" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in newer browsers:

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type` and `autoComplete` into the `inputProps`:

```
<TextField
    placeholder="password"
    onChange={(e) => setFieldValue("password", e.target.value)}
    inputProps={{
        type: "password",
        autoComplete: 'new-password'
    }}
/>
```