# In Node.js/Express, how do I disable browser cache for a redirect?

Tags: node.js, http, caching, express

```
app.get('/my_profile_picture', function(req,res){
    getPicture(req.user.id, function(url){
        res.redirect(url);  
    });
});
```

This is my code.  However, when the user **changes** his profile picture, the browser still goes to the old picture's URL.  It's because the browser has the "redirect" cached or something.

How do I change the response in Express so that there is no cache at all?

Comment: See also [How to force Chrome NOT to cache redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553420/how-to-force-chrome-not-to-cache-redirects?) - unanswered at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the redirect to be a `307` redirect (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) as they shouldn't be cached by default.

```
app.get('/my_profile_picture.jpg', function(req,res){
    getPicture(req.user.id, function(url){
        res.statusCode = 307;
        res.redirect(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: According to the HTTP spec, 307 should not be necessary to avoid caching. Express by default does 302 for `res.redirect`, and a 302 response "is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field." However, Chrome has [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103458) which causes redirects to be cached. According to a commenter, this applies to 307 redirects as well. So beware.

Comment: @MerynStol I'm surprised that bug *still* hasn't been fixed! It's over a year and a half old!