# <img> onload handler fails to fire for dataURI

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-uri

I am having trouble getting the onLoad handler to fire when an the `src` attribute of  `<img>`  is loaded with a dataURI. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnsME/7/).

This appears to be a browser compatibility issue.

- Handler fires as expected in Firefox.
- Handler fires only once in Chrome.
- Handler fires as expected in IE.

I would like the handler to fire every time a dataURI is loaded into the `<img>`, even if the dataURI being loaded is identical to a previous dataURI.

I suspect this is related to the cache in Google Chrome. With 'ordinary image loads', this can be solved by adding a `?refresh={timestamp}` to the URL ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553420/how-to-force-chrome-not-to-cache-redirects)).

Any ideas how to force Chrome to actually load a dataURI, even if it is cached?

**clarification:**

The behavior in Firefox & IE meets my requirements. I would like Chrome to exhibit the same behavior...

Comment: check my answer, updated it

Comment: Sorry but why do you need to fire a load event multiple times on that same image? This may cause confusion to many developers in the future.
Also any image modifications would change the result base64. Consider changing your logic or please explain your motivation

Comment: 1. Why do you need to update the same `<img>` with the same uri multiple times? 2. Why do you need to listen for that even with `.load`?  This sounds like a design problem.

Comment: The reason for this design? Here is the short answer: We have some complicated artificial intelligence running on the server, on large image files. In order to prevent multiple uploads/downloads of the same file, we keep it in the client as a dataURI. As the AI progresses on the server, the image is moved from one `<img>` to the next on the client. The above problem occurs if a user uploads the same image twice. Could it have been designed differently/better? Perhaps. But we are already pretty far along in this project. Luckily, there is a simple but effective work-around (see @Ergec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Chrome** you can use

```
<button onclick="$('#copy').attr('src', '');$('#copy').attr('src', $('#original').attr('src'));">copy image</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AnsME/16/

**For Explorer**

JSFiddle gives error for JQuery. It doesn't load at all. Try testing code in a regular html file.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! (The problem was in Chrome only; worked fine in FF and IE.)

Answer (score -1):

As far as the Chrome/Safari issue, your event delegation was only being applied to that first existing element. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AnsME/11/

```
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function () {
    var $original = $('#original');
    var $clone = $original.clone();
    $clone.load(function () {
        $('body').append('on load firing number ' + ++count + '<br>' );
    });
    $original.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: This changes the behavior, which is **not** what is required. I do not want to create 3rd or 4th items. The point is that the `<img id="copy">' must stay in place. The dataURI needs to be copied multiple times into that same element; as illustrated in my original fiddle.