# iOS7 - <select> menu not reset on history.back / browser back button

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu, ios7, back

This is a strange bug that occurs on the iPhone 5 when navigating back to a previous page.

Here's the steps to reproduce the bug on an iPhone 5:

1. Select a menu option that directs to a new page
2. From the new page press the browser back button
3. Try and navigate to the same page again using the same menu

An example page to try this on [is here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/navigation/drop-menu.html). On this page, select 'Javascript Tutorials' from the first menu on the page. Then follow steps above...

In my situation there is no go button to follow the link (like the second menu on the example page). The option is followed when clicked. The problem with this is that because the page you returned from is selected in the menu, you are unable to navigate to it. You cant re-select it.

My question: Is this a known iOS 7 bug? And is there a solution? My search has come up empty so far.

My JS code selects the first option when the menu is generated on page load. And as said, this bug only occurs on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* an iOS 7/iPhone 5 bug.
I can recreate it in Chrome on Windows 7.

As you said,

1. "because the page you returned from is selected in the menu,
2. you are unable to navigate to it"

---

1. The menu is pre-selected because of autocomplete behavior

   - When you press browser "back" in step 2 (versus page refresh), browser remembers the state you left the select in
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699400/1175496
2. When you re-select an option that is already selected

   - You haven't changed anything; so the change event doesn't fire
   - Scripts listening for that event (as with the **onChange** attribute in your example) won't send you to the page

I fix this by putting *autocomplete="off"* attribute on the **form** element containing your select;
this prevents number 1, which prevents number 2.

Comment: adding autocomplete="off" did not solve the issue :( im looking into using the unload event...