# Firefox password field is prepopulated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, browser, html-input

I have the following code:

```
 <dl class="dl-table">
                         <dt style="width:170px">Current Password:</dt>
                            <dd>
                               @Html.Password("CurrentPassword", "")
                            </dd>
                           <dt style="width:170px">New Password:</dt>
                            <dd>
                              @Html.Password("NewPassword", "")
                            </dd>
                           <dt style="width:170px">Confirm New Password:</dt>
                            <dd>
                              @Html.Password("ConfirmNewPassword", "")
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
```

But, for some reason, it is displayed like this:

[image]

Why is it pre-populating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make page to tell browser not to cache/preserve input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284/make-page-to-tell-browser-not-to-cache-preserve-input-values)

Comment: Yeah I suspect it is caching your last input. Try turning that off. If it doesn't solve it I would look at how the page is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `autocomplete="off"`

```
@Html.Password("ConfirmNewPassword", "", new { autocomplete = "off" } )
```