# jQuery fill empty text input with default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to fill the suchfeld `<input>` with `"Suche..."`.

```js
$(function() {
    var suchfeld = $("#suchfeld");


    suchfeld.on("focus", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == "Suche..." ) {
            suchfeld.val("");
        }
    });

    suchfeld.on("blur", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == 0 ) {
            suchfeld.val("Suche...");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="suchfeld" type="text"/>
```

The problem is that after the user has the site loaded with the suchfeld `<input>` and the site is in the cache of browser, if the user comes back to the loaded site the `<input>` is empty without `"Suche..."`.

What can I do?

Comment: tried placeholder attribute?

Comment: Nice man! That works for :-)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284/make-page-to-tell-browser-not-to-cache-preserve-input-values

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Javascript use [`placeholder`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Suche...">
```

**Side note:**

To hide the `placeholder` on `focus` (like in your example) use:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Suche..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
     onblur="this.placeholder = 'Suche...'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting on the page load the field to "Suche..."

```
$(function() {
    var suchfeld = $("#suchfeld");
    suchfeld.val("Suche...");

    suchfeld.on("focus", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == "Suche..." ) {
            suchfeld.val("");
        }
    });

    suchfeld.on("blur", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == 0 ) {
            suchfeld.val("Suche...");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no reload when the user comes back to the page. This example doesn't solve it!

Comment: Why don't you try using a placeholder instead?