# Prevent using back button to see information on previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, webforms

I have a form where users enter input. I want to prevent a different person from going back using the back button, and seeing what the first person entered.

I realize this is a problem only on the same browser etc. but that might be a problem sometimes.

I tried both `Server.Transfer()` and `Response.Redirect()` but both don't prevent it. I also tried setting the textboxes' (`asp:TextBox`) Text to empty in the event handler for the submit button in codebehind, but it still didn't work since the transfer overrode that.

The technology it WebForms. This is a given. I'm doing everything in codebehind, and would prefer solving this from there as well, if possible.

Comment: _"I also tried making the textboxes' Text to empty, but it still didn't work since the transfer overrode that."_ - How exactly did you do that? I would've tried using Javascript on the previous page and subscribed to the [`window.onbeforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), making it clear all the sensitive information.

Comment: @VisualVincent I did that on the button submit event handler in codebehind.

Comment: Ah. Well yes then it's likely too late. It should be done on the frontend before leaving the page.

Comment: I'd suggest a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284/make-page-to-tell-browser-not-to-cache-preserve-input-values and `<%@ OutputCache NoStore="true" VaryByParam="*" Location="None" %>` on the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the data from the backend (codebehind) will be too late as the redirect will, as you say, happen before the change occurs.

Instead I suggest you use Javascript on the frontend, subscribe to the [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event and use that to clear your page before the redirect takes place.

An example implementation can look like:

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    //Iterate all <input> elements on the page.
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];

        //Ignore all elements that don't have type="text" or type="password" (we don't want to clear buttons, etc.).
        if(["text", "password"].indexOf(input.type.toLowerCase()) < 0) { continue; }

        //Clear the element's value.
        input.value = "";
    }
});
```

I gave it a brief test: Right before redirecting you'll notice the text boxes being cleared, and when you return by pressing the Back button the text boxes are still empty.