# How to remove saved responses from a field in Flask-WTForms for patient privacy?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, privacy

I built an app for work that keeps track of client medications.

Although of course I did not include any client data when I deployed the app in order to be able to demonstrate it to employers, in the dropdown fields you can still see the initials of the clients.

I'm putting it in maintenance mode in between showing it, and I also added a bunch of fake records so that you can only see the real initials mixed in with other random initials (and again, only under the fields in the automatically generated dropdown menus, not in the actual data saved to the database). Since there's no other information about the clients, I think that's pretty much all I **really** need to do.

But all of this begs a more programmatic solution: **how do I edit the previous values that Flask-WTF remembers so that you cannot see them in the dropdown?**

Here is what I mean: [image: Dropdown menu with previous form entries]

Please let me know what options I have!

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this the browser caching the values? If so, see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699400/2800058)

Comment: I thought that too, but when I went to the app on my phone I could still see them, and I didn't add any records via mobile. I tried deleting my history including cache and cookies and that did not change what displayed...

Comment: Hmm, I will try setting autocomplete to off as well...

Comment: Setting autocomplete to off did the trick.