# JavaScript Input field gets the old value on loading

Tags: javascript

I have an input field:

```
<input id="RangeRate1" type="range" min="125.00" max="500.00" value="250.00">
```

When I reload the page, the value of the input is set to what was set the last time the range slider was changed.  For instance, if the rate was changed to 300 prior to page reload, when the page reloads, if I console out the value of the range slider:

```
let RateSlider = document.querySelector("RangeRate1")
console.log("existing rate: ", RateSlider.value)
```

I get 300! even though the html input value is still shown as 250.00 as above.  When I use `ctrl shift r`, the correct number is displayed, in this case the value I see in the input HTML code, 250. So, is there a way to flush out the old value or overwrite it with the actual value in the input tag lin?

Comment: From the answers I'm reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699284 you need to place them into a form and use `autocomplete=off` as a property of the `<form>` tag.  Warning, Chrome ignores this same named property for fields, but based on the comments in the above question I believe it honors them for the form. I haven't tested this solution myself so I'm leaving it here in the comments for you to try. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers do this for "convenience" purposes even though it's less than convinient

You can just use some JavaScript to set the actual value to the attribute value (unless the attribute itself is also set by the browser to last value, in which case just set it to the hard coded value itself)

```
let RateSlider = document.querySelector("#RangeRate1")

RateSlider.value=parseInt(RateSlider.getAttribute("value"))
```

EDIT
alternatively if the input is part of a form (assuming form has id if "myForm") you can reset it

```
myForm.reset()
```

Comment: That worked, sort of. Now I get the correct 250.00 number, but the thumb of the slider is still stuck at the old number.  How do I reset the slider thumb?

Comment: @johnny no I mean exactly what I said, autocorrect on phone

Comment: @bluejayke the initial data of the rate slider is set using ```<input id="RangeRate1" type="range" min="125.00" max="500.00" value="250.00">```, I read the value to do other calculations using the ```RateSlider.value=parseInt(RateSlider.getAttribute("value"))```, so where do I change the value in the input tag to fix the thumb from sticking to the old value?

Comment: @early what do you mean, did The JavaScript not work when put in <script> tags?

Comment: I have my JS code in an external file.  Your suggestion worked in that when I read the value from the input, it is what I expected it to be, which is the value in the input tag.  However, the thumb of the slider should read from the value of the input, but it does NOT. So, when I load the page, it somehow reads from the previous value of the input.