# Firefox cache textarea value?

Tags: html, firefox, textarea

I found a strange issue. Open a simple page in Firefox, the code is simple as below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, I type some characters in the textarea. Then I click refresh button of the browser. Surprisingly, after the page refreshed, what I typed is still there in textarea. However, if I just focus on URL bar and press ENTER key, the textarea is clear after refreshing.

I reproduced this in Firefox 3.6.12 in Linux and 3.6.3 in MacOS. And, I have only Firebug extension installed so it should NOT be due to Firefox extension.

Is this a know issue?
How to make textarea clear after Refresh button is clicked?

Comment: You sound surprised, but this isn't new behavior.  Firefox has done this for as long as I can remember (and I've been using Firefox since its version numbers started with "M"!).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For textarea only:

```
<textarea autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

For all form fields

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

[Preventing Firefox from remembering the input value on refresh with Meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remebering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag)

Answer (score 2):

It's so that your form information is kept if you accidentally navigate away from the page and then return by using the previous or next button.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
<script>document.form.reset();</script>
```

or

```
onload="document.FORMNAME.reset();
```

which will avoid `aufill` on refresh.