# Why is jquery showing that the 'disabled' property exists when I refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<input type = 'file'>`. To enable/disable it I use `jQuery("#my_input").prop('disabled' ,true/false)`.

If I disable it, then refresh the page, jQuery outputs:

```
console.log(jQuery("#my_input").prop('disabled' )) ==> true
```

even though the 'disabled' prop is **not** included in the html.

Clearing the cache does not fix it.

Comment: Either you have some other code that toggles it or you are using Firefox.

Comment: Please post the html for this also, something else must be disabling it!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté ... firefox, yes.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS ... I have a consoe.log method directly before the .prop method, and the first message indicates that the 'disabled' property is already present (if prior to refresh, it had been last disabled)

Comment: <form autocomplete="off">

see: [SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263536/firefox-cache-textarea-value

Comment: OR ... <input type = 'file'  autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox has long been saving input values through refreshes, and now the latest builds also save `input` / `button`'s disabled status through refreshes.

I'm not sure whether this is intended or a bug, but for the time being an workaround is to just set the inputs' `disabled` status to their default ones inside a DOM ready handler.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#my_input").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Demonstrating the issue: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yNH6M/4/show) (open with Firefox)
And now fixed with the snippet above: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yNH6M/5/show)

---

You can also apply `autocomplete="off"` to the element and its disabled status won't persist through refreshes.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yNH6M/6/show)

Note that this will prevent any form of auto-completion in the element. Of course, this is an excellent solution for file inputs and buttons, however depending on your use case (e.g. when it involves text inputs) you may prefer the former solution. Thanks to @dsdsdsdsd for the tip!

---

p.s. This has been reported to Mozilla already: [Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072).

Comment: Nice info. My fiddle works fine, sounds like your answer is good! http://jsfiddle.net/yNH6M/

Comment: "Firefox has long been saving input values through refreshes" led me to this: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263536/firefox-cache-textarea-value) which has a solution that worked: `<form autocomplete="off">`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd yes nice to mention that, though `autocomplete="off"` completely disables autocompletion right? That doesn't work very well for all use cases, but yeah it kills the post-refresh values keeping.

Comment: yes you're right ... maybe applying it to the form element is a little too nuclear-bomb-ish ... could apply the attribute directly to the input element instead of the form.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd that's worth a try. `=]` Let's see

Comment: @scrowler thanks for the fiddle, I've made some adaptions and added to the answer. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté if you'll add the discussion about the autocomplete to your answer, I would think that a reader would have a solid set of possibilities to solve their problem.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Just did. `=]` Was still testing, I'll add a fiddle and a note.

Comment: fyi i (and at least a couple other people i've spoken too) use a greasemonkey script that blanket nukes `autocomplete="off"` because it's almost always used for terrible reasons like preventing password storage.  so you might want to go with the less nuclear approach of restoring form state explicitly.

Comment: @Eevee Yes, I tend to disable autocompletion as a last-resort approach, and that is an use case that I didn't think of. I really hope this to be a short-lived bug, well I'll browse bugzilla a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox should include it in html also.

What happens if you use:

```
jQuery("#my_input").attr('disabled' ,true)
```