# Browser caching select tag state and ignoring selected="true"

Tags: html, browser

I'm rendering a drop down box that contains a currently selected value using `selected="true"`.

```
<select id="dropDown"> 
    <option selected="true" value="1">value2</option>
    <option value="2">value3</option>
    <option value="3">value4</option>
</select>
```

Initially the selected value corresponds to the `selected="true"`, but if I play around with the drop down box and then refresh the page the `selected="true"` is ignored and the displayed value is the last one I chose. I tried using `selected="selected"` with the same results. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remebering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your select field to `<select id="dropDown" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: My goodness!  I found this issue through perfectly semantic code.  Can you expand upon why this works?

Answer (score 0):

For best browser support it's actually (although it seems so dumb) better to use

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

[To quote MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
> even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
> behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
> forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a random string to the
> attribute [...] Since this random value is not a valid one, the browser will give
> up.

Answer (score -1):

It's a binary value, not an attribute (for some reason). Use:

```
<option selected="selected" value="1">value2</option>
```

or:

```
<option selected value="1">value2</option>
```

Comment: I tried that approach, it does not change the behavior. Thanks though.

Comment: While you're right about the syntax of the selected value, he's looking to stop the page from caching the changed field value.

Comment: Did you ever think that perhaps the browser is caching your last choice?

Comment: I knew it was caching it, I want to stop caching it. Maybe I should have communicated that better. BTW I didn't down-vote you.

Comment: You can also accomplish this by using document.forms[0].reset() (or whatever form name you're using)