# How can I make the browser remember previous input?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing Firefox from remebering the input value on refresh with Meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remebering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag)

For a simple text input, the browser usually "remembers" the user last inputs in the same fields.

[image]

Sometimes, for security reasons I suppose, some websites somehow prevent the input from remembering what the user typed. So I need to type my username every time I want to log into the website (double clicking the input field does not give me the dropdown list with the previously typed usernames).

Do you know if there's a HTML/JS property to prevent inputs from being remembered (under firefox), so I can override it and make the browser remember my input ?

Comment: For Firefox see [autoformer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autoformer/). Does the trick.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remebering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag

Comment: there's no `autocomplete="off"` in the input i'm talking about. But i've just noticed that the `submit` event for the form is overriden by a javascript function. Could that be it ?

Comment: I think the question is about getting other users' browsers to remember input, not setting up your own browser with an extension.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i would like to understand what prevents my input to be stored?

Comment: @Jacob it's actually both, I do need some other websites to remember my input and also understand how can this be prevented or enabled

Comment: @rkm yes, there actually is an autocomplete="off" attribute in the form tag, and not in the input tag. So problem solved. Thanks :)

Comment: @jidma - Would you like a web site to remember your bank details? Perhaps that is ok for your browser that is sat in the study in YOUR house. But go to a (lets say( public library) and you forget to logout properly - what do you expect to happen? The client (browser) software is free as a bird to store data. It is up to you to protect the data that is precious to you.

Comment: well i'm actually talking about remembering my bank accout number on my *own* computer because i keep forgetting it.. I just want to use firebug to edit html to enable *input remembering* in the browser every time i want to input the required info, hence my question..

Comment: @jidma - Use autoformer. But ensure that you need to type in the pass code to its moral equivalent.

Comment: @EdHeal what do you mean by moral equivalent ?

Comment: @jidma - moral equivalent -> in essence the same thing.

Comment: @EdHeal thank you and forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: @jidma -It was a idiom. English is like that.