# Firefox & reloading page: keeps unsubmitted value for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, firefox, browser-cache

I have a page that contains a select element for creating a new object.

When a user visits the page, if he/she selects a value from the select element and then reloads the page (using `cmd|ctrl + R`) the select keeps the value even though the value was never submitted.

**I don't want the option to be remembered upon reloading since it was never submitted**.

I tried adding in my application controller a before filter in order to disable cache:

```
before_filter :disable_cache

def disable_cache
  expires_now
end
```

Using a browser tool (HttpFox) I get the response header:

```
Cache-control no-cache, private
```

and the response body has no selected option in it **but while rendering, user's selected option before the reloading of the page is still there**.

Response body:

```
<select class="select optional" id="an_id" name="a_name">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

An actual reset for the select happens only when using `cmd|ctrl + shift + r`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a default "selected" option?

Comment: No, nothing selected. I will provide the response body on my original post in a minute.

Comment: Can you add the "selected" attribute to your `value=""` option?  I don't know much about ruby-on-rails, but I'd think that would fix it.

Comment: @eidsonator Nope, not an option since this will default to the "" value even if the user **has submitted another value**.

Comment: Workaround: I had to disable autocomplete.

From [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: I had to disable autocomplete.

Either on specific element or the the hole form.

I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag)