# Stop auto populating email and password for sites forms

Tags: forms, firefox

I have come across this a few times but always just cleared history and saved data to combat it but now I need it to stop for clients.

The user will log into their account and will choose to save login details i.e email and password. However in the site there is a section were the account user can add new users where they will have to enter an email address and password. The problem is that in FF these fields are prepopulated with the account users details. Even if I remove the email field and reload the page then the email goes into the surname field.

Is there any way to fix this problem as some of the users may not be used to computers.

Comment: Do you control the form or just the browser? If you control the underlying HTML, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add `autocomplete="off"` to your input elements.

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: You can also add this to the `<form>` element to disable autocomplete for all the input elements within it. Just be aware that using autocomplete breaks standards compliance...

Comment: This does fix my problem but is there any way to do it without removing the autocomplete. Seems like a big FF flaw