# Firefox: bizarre bug (maybe some autocompletion glitch)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Basically, I suspect Firefox to overwrite my preset value in an input. It happens when pressing F5 on a page where there is an input of which the preset value has been changed. The previous value is being displayed on screen. If I go into url bar and press enter, the correct (fresh) value appears.

This is the piece of my (django) template:

```
{{ reply_recipients_id_list }}
<input class="text" type="text" value="{{ reply_recipients_id_list }}" placeholder="Recipients" name="recipients" id="id_recipients">
```

This is renderred html:

```
 1,33
<input id="id_recipients" class="text" type="text" name="recipients" placeholder="Recipients" value="1,33">
```

However, there is different value displayed as you can see in the picture:

[image]

**(!) Javascript is switched off for the page (!)**

Comment: The rendered HTML works in FF for me.

Comment: Firefox preserves input values on refresh. Try using `autocomplete="off"` attribute on your input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-meta-tag

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: autocomplete="off" solved the issue.